# PrimeFaces enter key is interligne

Tags: primefaces, editor, blur

i have dataTable,in therein(dataTable) i have two edits columns of type inputTextarea  but when i presse enter key for insert interline in my inputTextarea the data saved.
how i can insert interline and how i can replace event="cellEdit" by event="blur"

```
  <p:ajax event="cellEdit" listener="#{beanListTache.onCellEdit}" update=":form:growl" />
    <p:column headerText="#{messages.PlanningServiceProgression}" style="width:75px;background-color:##{lineBgColor};">
               <p:cellEditor>
                   <f:facet name="output"><div style="height: 95px;"><h:outputText value="#{tache.progression}" style="white-space:pre-wrap !important;font-size:10px; "/></div></f:facet>
                   <f:facet name="input"><p:inputTextarea value="#{tache.progression}" style="width:100%;height: 95px !important;" label="Progression"/></f:facet>
               </p:cellEditor>
            </p:column>
<p:column headerText="#{messages.PlanningServiceObservations}" style="margin-left: -10px;background-color:##{lineBgColor};">
           <p:cellEditor>
               <f:facet name="output"><div style="height: 95px;"><h:outputText value="#{tache.observation}" style="white-space:pre-wrap !important;font-size: 10px;"/></div></f:facet>
               <f:facet name="input"><p:inputTextarea value="#{tache.observation}" style="width:100%;height: 95px !important;"  label="Observation"/></f:facet>
           </p:cellEditor>
        </p:column>
```

and my bean is:

```
public void onCellEdit(CellEditEvent event) {
        Object oldValue = event.getOldValue();
        Object newValue = event.getNewValue();
        if(!newValue.equals("") && !newValue.equals(oldValue)) {
            Def d=tacheService.trouver(Integer.parseInt(event.getRowKey())).getDef();
            if(event.getColumn().getHeaderText().equals("Progression")){
                d.setProgression(newValue.toString());
            }else{
                d.setObservation(newValue.toString());
            }
            defService.modifier(d);
            FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, "Cell Changed", "Commentaire bien enregistrer");
            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, msg);
        }
    }
```

Comment: i need help please

Comment: Can anyone let me know how I can avoid this?Thanks.